# can get data from database but unable to update record to the database from context listener class

Tags: java, sql-server, stored-procedures

I created context listener class in which I am creating a scheduler task using Executor class. From that task I am calling database.
context listener class

```
@WebListener
public class WebAppServletListener implements ServletContextListener{
private DailyNotificationSchedular dailySchedular;
private ImmediateNotificationSchedular immediateSchedular;
@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
    System.out.println("Context is started !");
    //dailySchedular = DailyNotificationSchedular.getSchedular();
    //dailySchedular.start();
    immediateSchedular = ImmediateNotificationSchedular.getSchedular();
    immediateSchedular.start();
}
@Override
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
    dailySchedular.stop();
    immediateSchedular.stop();
}
}
```

where start method looks like follow

```
public void start() {
    System.out.println("daily notification started !");
    System.out.println(this.getProperties().getProperty("dailyrule"));
    try {
        final Runnable dailyTask = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                NotificationRuleHandler rh = new NotificationRuleHandler();
                List<Rule> scheduledRules = rh.getAllRules("IMMEDIATE");
                Iterator itr = scheduledRules.iterator();
                while(itr.hasNext()) {
                    rh.processNotificationRule((Rule)itr.next());
                }
            }
        };
        this.scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(dailyTask, 0, 15, TimeUnit.MINUTES);// replace time interval from bw properties
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

in **getAllRules()** method I m calling stored procedure which yields expected records

```
callableStatement = connection.prepareCall("{CALL BW_GET_NOTIFICATION_RULES_SPECIFIC(?)}");
```

now using same database creds I am trying to insert records into the database with SP,

```
callableStatementUpdate = connection.prepareCall("{CALL UPDATE_EMAIL_NOTIFICATION_LOG_IMMEDIATE(?,?,?,?,?)}");
int r = callableStatementUpdate.executeUpdate();
```

now when I try to print the *r* it gives result as *-1*

So basically after lot of debugging I came to conclusion that I am able to get the data from database but not able to update the data into table. Can someone tell me why is this happening ?
**Same thing if I try from any servlet file then it works fine**

Comment: did you try doing a profiler trace on the SQL side?

Comment: Did you get any exception? Where did you set the parameter values for the SP call?

Comment: If you manually run the update SP in SSMS, does it work?